# When upgrading node from 6 to latest, npm i fails with ENOENT in react native project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, cocoapods, node-modules

When upgrading to newer versions of npm from 6.14 to latest on react native project

Using node 14, nvm to switch node versions, ideally i'd like to go to node 16, but a similar issue happens regardless of 14 or 16 when updating npm in particular.

I'm also using homebrew on mac M1

I notice the Jetify command asks me:

Jetifier found 1390 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
Need to install the following packages:
pod
Ok to proceed? (y)

when i select y, npm i fails. I've cleared cache's and removed node_modules. normal cache clearing attempts don't seem to work.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /Users/user/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/user/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-01-28T21_51_28_303Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! code 254
npm ERR! path /Users/user/repos/MyApp/My-MobileApp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npx jetify && cd ios && npx pod install && cd .. && ./node_modules/.bin/patch-package
```

Here is part of the complete log -

```
    3325 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
3326 timing command:exec Completed in 42372ms
3327 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/user/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2'
3328 verbose cwd /Users/user/repos/MyApp/MyApp-MobileApp/ios
3329 verbose Darwin 21.2.0
3330 verbose argv "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "pod" "install"
3331 verbose node v14.18.3
3332 verbose npm  v8.4.0
3333 error code ENOENT
3334 error syscall chmod
3335 error path /Users/user/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
3336 error errno -2
3337 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/user/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2'
3338 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
3338 error enoent
3339 verbose exit -2
3340 timing npm Completed in 42533ms
3341 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1643406718315
3342 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1643406730346
3343 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1643406730346
3344 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1643406730347
3345 verbose unfinished npm timer build:link 1643406730354
3346 verbose unfinished npm timer build:link:node_modules/pod 1643406730356
3347 verbose code -2
3348 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
3348 error     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-01-28T21_51_28_303Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is related to not finding the pm2 package from pod dependency.

Not sure if this will work properly with npx, you might need to install pod globally to get this working.

```
npm install pod -g
pod install // instead of npx pod install
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pod#installation

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm rebuild` they say to use **"only when you upgrade the node version and must recompile"**

Comment: bunch of deprecation warnings then failed with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

hello i once faced this type of issue and issue was  actually because pm2 or some other package or processes on old node which was used in your app wasnt found in the updated node version
Reinstall your pm2 package and other package used by your old node in your code again and try again

let me know if this helps you