# How to update npm version with React Native homebrew?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, homebrew

I'm trying to update react native project to use a newer version of node.

I use the node version manager typically to switch to newer versions of node, but I'm trying to switch npm to a newer version. It sees a deprecated lockfile then fails.

from npm 6 to latest npm 8

when i use the global install command npm i -g npm@latest
it works, but then I get a message

Need to install the following packages:
pod
Ok to proceed? (y)

which fails on

```
npm ERR! path /Users/johndoe/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
```

Comment: Do you have any sample repo that I can take a look?

Comment: I don't, only can provide my feedback and output from commands. Any specific npm file I can share. I am using homebrew.

Comment: unfortunately, it is very hard for me to interpret or understand what is going on there.

Comment: Here is a post I made about it a few months ago if you'd like additional info please let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900791/when-upgrading-node-from-6-to-latest-npm-i-fails-with-enoent-in-react-native-pr